# Maven War overlay creates files with no extensions

Tags: java, spring, maven, war, overlays

for the need of my project I need to use maven-war-plugin (War Overlays).
I created main war application and another war application consisting everything specific for the module.

When I run an application in Eclipse I can see that the second application is merged with the first one, but the files does not have extensions and in each folder there is just one file.

If I open other folders - there proper files (JavaScript, classes, ...)

Here is an example (instead of a class file I get this):
[image: after merge]

Here is my configuration:

```
<build>
<finalName>com.objectverse</finalName>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <overlays>
        <overlay>
          <groupId>com.objectverse</groupId>
          <artifactId>com.objectverse.tcs.news</artifactId>
        </overlay>
        <overlay>
          <!-- empty groupId/artifactId represents the current build -->
        </overlay>
      </overlays>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

What do I have to do that the files from another war project will be just copied to my main application?

Regards,
 Bojan

Comment: This might be due to Windows hiding known file types.  Unzip the generated file and investigate with tools you know well.  Also 7zip is really good at navigating inside zipfiles.

Comment: I'm running my application from eclipse. I checked that already and still got the same result. I guess if I run my app from eclipse in folder C:\springsource\sts-2.8.0.RELEASE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myapplication everything should be merged right.

Comment: I found out what the problem was. I was using STS 2.8.0. As soon I upgraded to the latest STS the problem went away. Tnx